# html5 cache manifest setting up

Tags: html, html5-appcache

According to the manual I read online, in order to use cache manifest, I need to do the following two steps:
1. I need to add 'AddType text/cache-manifest .manifest' in a .htaccess file.
the question is where can I find .htaccess file? 
2. compose a new file called offline(DIY name).manifest.
Question is: where should I put this file? Is it under www file or somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

If I am right, both files should be in your root of that page. Same place where your HTML file is.